# Generating M or F for a 100 data point Python

Tags: python, numpy, shuffle

Is there a way of generating a random sample of Male and Female for my dataframe in Python? Doesnt have to be 50:50 but random every time I ran it? Thanks.

Comment: Create a basic odd or even program and feed it random numbers, if it's odd then M if even then F, and use df.apply to add it to df, or make a string of it and add it to df

Comment: @nenad.popovic, thanks for your kind words of encouragement. I obviously did my research first and I kept coming up with a random name generator and other generators to do with integers not strings. So please keep your presumptions to yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise a RNG object and use its choice method:

```
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng()
values = rng.choice(['M', 'F'], size=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

sample = ['M' if random.randint(0, 1) == 1 else 'F' for _ in range(100)]
```

Output:

```
['M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M']
```

Comment: If using the `random` module - you might as well use `random.choices`, eg: `sample = random.choices(['M', 'F'], k=100)`

Comment: You're perfectly right, a wonderful alternative!